# Add leading zero and convert as varchar to a float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data where I need to add leading zeros to it. But the problem is the data type is float. So whenever I add zeros, it automatically omits them. I have tried to add leading zero to it then try to convert it to varchar(50).

I used following query (thanks to Mr. Damien_The_Unbeliever):

```
select  '0' + convert (varchar(50), (wallet_sys)) as wallet_sys  from NewSysData1
```

However the result is showing: 01.72295e+009 instead of showing like this: 01718738312

What should I do?

PS: Some of the sample data are below:

```
1718738312, 8733983312, 9383879312
```

I want these to be:

```
01718738312, 08733983312, 09383879312
```

Comment: Are you using float on purpose? Why not bigint or decimal?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: It simply be a dispay issue.  What are you using to view the results?

Comment: It becomes float when importing from excel. I am using SQL Server 2012 :)

Comment: I am using result pane of sql server @DanBracuk

Comment: Why do you care what the result pane of SQL Server shows? This has all kinds of presentation peculiarities. Unless your users are going to using Management Studio exclusively, you should worry about how the client / presentation layer displays the data, not Management Studio.

Comment: Till now we have only sql server to analyze huge chunk of data. We will try to go to a presentation layer later on this year. @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  the [str() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) and trim

```
select '0' + ltrim(rtrim(str(wallet_sys))) as wallet_sys from NewSysData1;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77883/1)

Comment: @Magnus yes, but OP doesn't ask for 01718738312.00 as result... so I stripped. `str(wallet_sys, 38, 10)` will give `08733983312.0000000000` for example, which doesn't look like the deisred result...

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the following:

```
select right('00' + convert(varchar, MONTH(getdate())),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select right(replicate('0',10)+cast(wallet_sys as varchar),11)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

> Syntax for CONVERT:
>
> > CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression **[ , style ]** )

-

> float and real Styles
>
> > When expression is **float** or **real**, style can be one of the values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.

-

```
Value          | Output
---------------+---------------------
0 (default)    | A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
1              | Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
2              | Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
126, 128, 129  | Included for legacy reasons and might be deprecated in a future release.
```

Note that none of the formatting options allow for any longer values that aren't in scientific notation.

Therefore what we have to do is convert to another type as an interim:

```
SELECT '0' + Convert(varchar(50), Convert(decimal(38, 10), Convert(float, '1.72295e+009'), 0))
```

Adjust the number of decimal places by changing the scale of the `decimal` type